# Make JavaScript Detect Buttons That Are Pressed In a Certain Order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a number keypad from 0 to 9 and when certain numbers get pressed in a certain order an `event` will happen.

So something like this

```
if ( button1 gets pressed then button2 then button3 )
    alert('You did the code!')
}
else {
    alert('You did not do the code')
}
```

No `jQuery` please

Thanks!

Comment: You need to store the sequence, or add up to a counter.

Comment: Read up on State Machines, draw a Flowchart, state diagram, it's fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//sequence is 358

//SOLUTION

sequence = {
  
 check : function(e){
  sequence.value += this.textContent;
 
   if (sequence.value == sequence.sequence)
     {
       alert(1);
       sequence.value = "";
     }
   else 
   {
     if (sequence.timer)
     {
        clearTimeout(sequence.timer);
     }
     sequence.timer = setTimeout("sequence.value=''", 1000);
   }
}, 
 
  value : "",
  sequence : "358"

}

//THIS CODE ATTACHES CLICK HANDLERS TO THE BUTTON, NOT PART OF THE SOLUTION

Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("button"), function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", sequence.check, false);
});

//end
```

```html
<button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br/>
<button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br/>
<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br/>
<button>0</button>
```

How does this work. I don't want to pollute the global scope with values so I used an object to store the variables and the `check` method in.

The object is called `sequence`.

It has three properties

> 1. `check`, the method that checks the input when a button is clicked.
> 2. `value`, that holds the sequence value until the correct sequence is found.
> 3. `sequence`, the property that holds the correct value.

Each button on the page is assigned with a click handler. When clicked it fires `sequence.check`. Via the `this` keyword (referring to the button) we extract the number (via `textContent`). We add that number to the value string. Then we check if the value matches the sequence. If so execute some code (in this case an alert) and reset the value.

There is a timer set. If the user doesn't enter a new number within a second the timer will reset the `value`. `setTimeout` does this. The `1000` stands for `1000 milliseconds = 1 second`.

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this by monitoring the `keydown` event, and if the key is a number, add in to an array. At the same time, check the array contents to see if they are in a certain defined order. If they are, fire whatever you need to do, if not, do nothing but add the key to the array. Once your sequence has been completed, clear the array to make way for a new sequence.

You could get complicated with things like, clearing the array after a certain interval of not completing the sequence etc.

Comment: Would an array be more efficient than just building a string? If so, how do you check the order of values in an array?

Comment: hmm good question. I suppose if it's something simple like, the user needs to input  `1 2 3 4 5 6` for something to happen you could just test the strings.

Comment: For this operation an array and a String would have the same efficiency, the difference is intent.  If you append to a string as buttons are pressed then you are just testing the growing string against a pattern that represents the correct order like `var pressed = "1|3|2|4|", valid = (pressed === "1|2|3|4|");` in this case valid would equal `false`.  If you did this with an array you would have to iterate over the array to test if they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple system that does part of what you are looking for:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
  i;

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var pressed = document.getElementById('pressed');
    pressed.value += this.value + "|";
    if (pressed.value === '1|2|3|') {
      alert('You unlocked it!');
    }
    if (pressed.value.length >= 6) {
      //Start over
      pressed.value = "";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<input id='pressed' type='text' />
<button value='1'>One</button>
<button value='2'>Two</button>
<button value='3'>Three</button>
```

Comment: Or if you really wanted to get fancy, here is an approach that uses `data` attributes to store the valid combination http://jsfiddle.net/s9v9mn4c/